# Google Earth cannot be installed on ubuntu 12.04 as it needs ia32-libs, but this cannot be installed for unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, google-earth

Downloading Google Earth 7.0 and the attempting to install with 
`sudo dpkg -i google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb`
results in this error message:

```
...
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von google-earth-stable:
 google-earth-stable hängt ab von ia32-libs; aber:
  Paket ia32-libs ist nicht installiert.
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten von google-earth-stable (--install):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
...
```

Trying to install the missing dependency ia32-libs results in further missing dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
...
Probieren Sie »apt-get -f install«, um dies zu korrigieren:
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 ia32-libs : Hängt ab von: ia32-libs-multiarch
E: Unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten. Versuchen Sie »apt-get -f install« ohne Angabe eines Pakets (oder geben Sie eine Lösung an).
```

Applying `apt-get -f install` is of no help. Trying to install `ia32-libs-multiarch` results in further missing dependencies, and so on.

I understand that `ia32-libs-multiarch` may not be needed anymore, but since Google Earth insists on having it, what can be done?

Comment: Please use `LANG=C  sudo dpkg -i google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb` and `LANG=C sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` and replace the current version.

Answer (score 0):

Try the package with *i386.deb (32-Bit-package).